# How can I set default option for select using selectize.js

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

I use selectize.js to create a select tag. I want to set the option default selected but it does not work.

Code:

```
$.each(dataArr, function(i, item)
{ 
  $("select[name='"+sel_name+"']").selectize()[0].selectize.addOption(
    { title:item,selected: 'true'})
});
```

Comment: post also your html

Comment: if your options are dynamic?

Comment: yes ！ all options created by loop

Comment: when the options created I hope they can be selected already

Comment: Not the same question, but [check out the snippet in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516582/selectize-additemvalue-adds-the-value-of-the-item-and-not-the-items-label/51523912#51523912) to see how to add the option and have it selected by default (you need to use `addItem()` after `addOption()`).